# Servlet filter prevents css from working

Tags: java, spring-mvc, servlet-filters

I'm working on a java project based on spring-MVC. I have users - students in this issue - which I'd like to check on each page they navigate, if they are logged it. So I wrote a web filter, that runs before each page loading and assures that user is logged in and is a student- except for login page ( obviously user is not logged in there :D) and home page which is reachable for everyone- however, when I added this filter to the project, all css got disabled, all images disappeared, and I suppose if I had any js that would get disabled too(That is just a guess, but I believe the page's access to Resource folder is somehow banned. Since I referred to it with this pattern:

`${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources`

Here is my filter's `doFilter` method, is there anything I'm getting wrong here?

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
    String loginURI = request.getContextPath() + "/studentLogin"; /* student login page */
    String mainPage = request.getContextPath() + "/"; /* ?! */

    boolean loggedIn = (session != null) && (session.getAttribute("type") != null) && (session.getAttribute("type") == "s");
    boolean loginRequest = request.getRequestURI().equals(loginURI);
    boolean isMainPage = request.getRequestURI().equals(mainPage);

    if (loggedIn || loginRequest||isMainPage) { //if: user is logged in, or user is attempting to login, or user is just looking at the main page and has nothing to do with us
        chain.doFilter(request, response);//let it go :d
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect(loginURI); //redirect user to login page!! this user mustn't be here!
    }
}
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow for your filter to bypass static resources, something like this:

```
boolean isStaticResource = request.getRequestURI().startsWith("/resources/");

if (loggedIn || loginRequest || isMainPage || isStaticResource) { 
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
} else {
    response.sendRedirect(loginURI);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast and efficient answer! It worked and soled the problem in one move. However, I'm not familiar with "static resources". could you please explain what did you mean by that?

Comment: @SarahAmini please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24108624/1126831).