# CSS and JS not working after applaying servelt filter

Tags: java, css, servlet-filters

it is the first time i use dofilter function for authenticating my jsp web application once added it and CSS and JS not working on any page, I made search over and over but can not apply the solutions in my code
find below dofilter method.

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;

    String servletPath = request.getServletPath();

    // User information stored in the Session.
    // (After successful login).
    UserAccount loginedUser = AppUtils.getLoginedUser(request.getSession());

    if (servletPath.equals("/login")) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    HttpServletRequest wrapRequest = request;

    if (loginedUser != null) {
        // User Name
        String userName = loginedUser.getUserName();

        // Roles
        List<String> roles = loginedUser.getRoles();

        // Wrap old request by a new Request with userName and Roles information.
        wrapRequest = new UserRoleRequestWrapper(userName, roles, request);
    }

    // Pages must be signed in.
    if (SecurityUtils.isSecurityPage(request)) {

        // If the user is not logged in,
        // Redirect to the login page.
        if (loginedUser == null) {

            String requestUri = request.getRequestURI();

            // Store the current page to redirect to after successful login.
            int redirectId = AppUtils.storeRedirectAfterLoginUrl(request.getSession(), requestUri);

            response.sendRedirect(wrapRequest.getContextPath() + "/login?redirectId=" + redirectId);
            return;
        }

        // Check if the user has a valid role?
        boolean hasPermission = SecurityUtils.hasPermission(wrapRequest);
        if (!hasPermission) {

            RequestDispatcher dispatcher //
                    = request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/accessDeniedView.jsp");

            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
            return;
        }
    }

    chain.doFilter(wrapRequest, response);
}
```

also find CSS link in pages

```
<link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
type="text/css">

<link
href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i"
rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Servlet filter prevents css from working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44702494/servlet-filter-prevents-css-from-working)

Comment: i found above question before adding my question but i dont know where to add it as it is the first time for me using this

Comment: is there any one have any can help me noting that i used below link to make the authentication "https://o7planning.org/en/11071/create-a-simple-login-application-and-secure-pages-with-java-servlet-filter"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally found the issue while deluging the project and it was related to remove "/" from Login servelt and to be @WebServlet({ "/login" })